# Formatando data com Laravel

Tags: laravel, data, formatação, laravel-5.4

Não estou conseguindo mudar o formato da data usando o `laravel 5.4`

Meu model está assim:

```
class Feriado extends Model{

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'data', 'descricao', 'created_at', 'updated_at' ];
    protected $dates = ['data'=> 'm-d-Y'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'feriados';

}
```

O controller que retorna os dados está assim:

```
public function index(){
        $feriados= Feriado::all();

        return response()->json(['error'=> false, 'mensagem'=> null, 'data'=> $feriados]);
    }
```

E o retorno está vindo assim:

```
{  
   "error":false,
   "mensagem":null,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "data":"2018-01-01 00:00:00",
         "descricao":"Confraterniza\u00e7\u00e3o Universal",
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "data":"2018-03-30 00:00:00",
         "descricao":"Sexta-feira Santa",
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "data":"2018-04-21 00:00:00",
         "descricao":"Tiradentes",
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null
      },
      {  
         "id":4,
         "data":"2018-05-01 00:00:00",
         "descricao":"Dia do Trabalhador",
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null
      },
      {  
         "id":5,
         "data":"2018-05-31 00:00:00",
         "descricao":"Corpus Christi",
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null
      },
      {  
         "id":6,
         "data":"2018-09-07 00:00:00",
         "descricao":"Independ\u00eancia do Brasil",
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null
      },
      {  
         "id":7,
         "data":"2018-10-12 00:00:00",
         "descricao":"Padroeira do Brasil",
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null
      },
      {  
         "id":8,
         "data":"2018-02-11 00:00:00",
         "descricao":"Finados",
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null
      },
      {  
         "id":9,
         "data":"2018-11-15 00:00:00",
         "descricao":"Proclama\u00e7\u00e3o da Rep\u00fablica",
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null
      },
      {  
         "id":10,
         "data":"2018-12-25 00:00:00",
         "descricao":"Natal",
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null
      }
   ]
}
```

A data está vindo no formato `2018-12-25 00:00:00` sendo que no model estou setando outro formato `protected $dates = ['data'=> 'm-d-Y'];`

Onde será que estou errando?

Para exibir os dados na tela estou usando angularjs, e mesmo usando um filtro `{{(feriado.data| date: 'dd-MM-yyyy')}}` não exibe na forma correta.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json leia isso .

Comment: consegui definir no model não :( mesmo  depois de tudo de novo...

Comment: Fiz uma resposta utilizando seu modelo tente entender e reflita no seu codigo o exemplo ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não mude nada no seu `model` na questão padrão, só faça um novo campo que será mostrado a partir dos resultados do mesmo, se quiser um data no padrão especifico, [crie um método que será anexado aos valores retornados de uma consulta, tanto array quanto json](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json), um ***exemplo minimo***:

Configure seu `Model`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Feriado extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'feriado';
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'data', 'descricao'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    //data formatada m-d-Y
    protected $appends = ['data2'];
    public function getData2Attribute()
    {
        return date('m-d-Y', strtotime($this->attributes['data']));
    }

}
```

essa configuração `$appends` só vai servir para mostrar dados, não tem relação com os campos quem fazem relação com a tabela, mas, os usam para mostrar determinados tipos de valores e formatos. O método `getData2Attribute()` tem a responsabilidade de fazer essa conversão e mostrar a data formatada (que pode ser de qualquer formato, depende da regra estabelecida), e tudo fica independente do padrão da tabela no banco é isso é útil para manter as operações sem problema de conversão, esse campo que foi anexado só é utilizado quando para mostrar informações nos métodos, exemplo:

```
>>> App\Models\Feriado::all()->toArray();    
=> [                                         
     [                                       
       "id" => 1,                            
       "data" => "2016-10-09",               
       "descricao" => "Festival",            
       "created_at" => "2017-10-27 00:00:00",
       "updated_at" => null,                 
       "data2" => "10-09-2016",              
     ],                                      
     [                                       
       "id" => 2,                            
       "data" => "2016-11-11",               
       "descricao" => "Carnaval",            
       "created_at" => "2017-10-27 00:00:00",
       "updated_at" => null,                 
       "data2" => "11-11-2016",              
     ],                                      
   ]                                         
>>>
```

nesse exemplo o campo anexado `data2` está no formato esperado. Há uma confusão no `Mutators` que tem a finalidade de mudar a característica de recuperação das informações do `Model`, que em muitos casos quebra a lógica e dá muitos problemas se for feito de maneira errado. É muito utilizado em campos Date ou `DateTime` (mas, qualquer campo pode haver uma empregabilidade), mas, precisa entender que a todo momento deverá utilizar as convenções da classe e formatar os dados e para atualizar suas informações deve ser um instância da classe `DateTime`, bem diferente do primeiro exemplo que é a melhor solução para o seu caso.

***Referencias:***

- [Eloquent: Serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization)
- [Serializing To Arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays)
- [Serializing To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json)
- [Appending Values To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a documentação do Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Altere isto:

```
protected $dates = ['data'=> 'm-d-Y'];
```

Para:

```
protected $dates = [
    'data'
];
```

E acrescente esta linha:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'm-d-Y';
```

Answer (score 1):

o formato do date do teu banco esta Y-m-d, que é o padrão, use função
$feriados->data->format('d/m/Y') na sua view.

Answer (score 0):

Tente a solução do David Santos, ela deve funcionar, mas uma alternativa caso não de certo, seria fazer a mudança na mão, é uma gambiarra mas funciona:

```
public function index(){
    $feriados= Feriado::all();
    foreach($feriados as $feriado){
        $feriado->data = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($feriado->data));
    }
    return response()->json(['error'=> false, 'mensagem'=> null, 'data'=> $feriados]);
}
```